# Alternative to .SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at VBA and my research tells that I should not use .SendKeys because it is unreliable. What alternative code should I use for the following?

`Application.SendKeys ("{Home}")`

Comment: That should read .SendKeys("Home")

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details on what is the application you are sending the keys to, and how does it launced?

Comment: You can use AutoIt or AutoHotKey instead of VBA if you're doing keyboard emulation. The reason people say sendkeys is unreliable is because usually there is programmatic access to whatever it is that person is trying to achieve. You would not "{up}{up}{right}" to get to a cell, you would just refer to the cell directly. E.g., Sheets(sht).cells(1,1).  So in your case, you need to ask yourself if there is a way to program it such that you're not using keyboard emulation.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to select the cell to the far left of the active selection, so with error handling:

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.Goto Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
```

Comment: I am using Application.SendKeys ("{Home}") while scraping from a  green screen machine. What alternative code do I use for that?

Comment: @Anthony What does the Home key do while scraping from the green screen machine? Can you provide some links, etc. to work on? If you make this less mysterious for us, we might be able to help more. Otherwise it sounds like "Can you help me to find my wallet?"

Comment: @Tehscript  Application.SendKeys ("{Home}") moves the the cursor to the top left field, the command line. My next bit of code is  Application.SendKeys ("{/FOR X203}")